# ERROR: blob.download_to_filename, return an empty file and raise error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download the *.tflite model on Google Cloud Storage to my Rapberry Pi 3B+ using the code as follows:

```py
export_metadata = response.metadata
export_directory = export_metadata.export_model_details.output_info.gcs_output_directory

model_dir_remote = export_directory + remote_model_filename # file path on Google Cloud Storage
model_dir = os.path.join("models", model_filename) # file path supposed to store locally

blob = bucket.blob(model_dir_remote)
blob.download_to_filename(model_dir)
```

However, this returns an empty file in my target directory locally, and meanwhile, raise an error:

```
# ERROR: google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 
# 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

# ERROR: google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 
# GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/ao-example/o/
# gs%3A%2F%2Fao-example%2Fmodel-export%2Ficn%2Fedgetpu_tflite-Test_Model12-2020-11-16T07%3A54%3A27.187Z%2Fedgetpu_model.tflite?alt=media: 
# ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

I guaranteed the corresponding authority to the service account. What confuses me is that when I use `gsutil` command, it works:

```
gsutil cp gs://ao-example/model-export/icn/edgetpu_model.tflite models/
```

Is anyone encountering the same problem? Is there any error in my code? Your help will be greatly appreciated!

---

I used the following code:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import automl
from google.cloud.storage import Blob

client = storage.Client(project="semesterproject-294707")
bucket_name = 'ao-example'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

model_dir_remote = "gs://ao-example/model-export/icn/edgetpu_tflite-Test_Model13-2020-11-18T15:03:42.620Z/edgetpu_model.tflite"

blob = Blob(model_dir_remote, bucket)

with open("models/edgetpu_model13.tflite", "wb") as file_obj:
        blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

This raises the same error, and return an empty file also... Still, I can use `gsutil cp` command to download the file...

---

(Edited on 06/12/2020)
The info of model generated:

```
export_model_details {
  output_info {
    gcs_output_directory: "gs://ao-example/model-export/icn/edgetpu_tflite-gc14-2020-12-06T14:43:18.772911Z/"
  }
}

model_gcs_path: 'gs://ao-example/model-export/icn/edgetpu_tflite-gc14-2020-12-06T14:43:18.772911Z/edgetpu_model.tflite'

model_local_path: 'models/edgetpu_model.tflite'
```

It still encounters the error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/ao-example/o/gs%3A%2F%2Fao-example%2Fmodel-export%2Ficn%2Fedgetpu_tflite-gc14-2020-12-06T14%3A43%3A18.772911Z%2Fedgetpu_model.tflite?alt=media: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

Still, when I use `gsutil cp` command, it works:

```
gsutil cp model_gcs_path model_local_path
```

---

Edited on 12/12/2020

Soni Sol's method works! Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Storage bucket.get\_blob to verified file path returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805849/google-cloud-storage-bucket-get-blob-to-verified-file-path-returns-none)

Comment: could you add a print of the 404 error that ypou are getting?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add some print statements for _export_metadata_ and _export_directory_ ? I have the theory that those values don't match with the "gs://" path you shared in the _gsutil_ command, causing the 404

Comment: Thanks! I checked the output. Supplemented in the question part:)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use something like this:

```
from google.cloud.storage import Blob

client = storage.Client(project="my-project")
bucket = client.get_bucket("my-bucket")

blob = Blob("file_on_gcs", bucket)

with open("/tmp/file_on_premise", "wb") as file_obj:
    blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```

[Blobs / Objects](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#module-google.cloud.storage.blob)

Comment: This raises the same error, and return an empty file also... Still, I can use `gsutil cp` command...

Answer (score 1):

When using the client libraries the `gs://` is not needed, also the name of the bucket is being passed twice on [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805849/google-cloud-storage-bucket-get-blob-to-verified-file-path-returns-none) they had a similar issue and got corrected.

please try with the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import automl
from google.cloud.storage import Blob

client = storage.Client(project="semesterproject-294707")
bucket_name = 'ao-example'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

model_dir_remote = "model-export/icn/edgetpu_tflite-Test_Model13-2020-11-18T15:03:42.620Z/edgetpu_model.tflite"

blob = Blob(model_dir_remote, bucket)

with open("models/edgetpu_model13.tflite", "wb") as file_obj:
        blob.download_to_file(file_obj)
```